# How do I require consumers a of class library to initialize static variables

Tags: c#, .net, class, variables, static

I am creating a DLL with lots of classes (also subclass).
One of them (kind of main class) has public static property like:

```
public static Guid Token { get; set; }
```

Then I send the compiled file to another person. The person connects the DLL as a reference to his / her project and then uses the particular class.

Is there an pattern / elegant way to force user to fill static property with value before using any class?

Comment: Is this some sort of licensing or authentication system? If so, strongest advice is to not try to build it yourself.

Comment: Nope, it is not. `Guid Token` is just a example. This static can be also string, int or other object.

Comment: Just write an explicit getter.  Complain by throwing an InvalidOperationException if it is still Guid.Empty, he'll wisen-up quickly.

Comment: Not elegant but acceptable. I will still wait for another offer. ;)

Comment: Is the whole class a static class or is this only (an example of) a static property of a non-static class? Or could there be both?

Comment: there is no way to force someone to fill a property. The only close way to do so is throwing exception when value is not set.

Comment: @Fidor Whole dll is non-static. Only one property is static.

Comment: @Franck Hans Passant already suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with static properties then you could require consumers to call an `Initialize` method:

```
public void InitializeThisGuidThatYouMustInitialize(Guid guid)
{
    // throw an exception if it's empty. Maybe throw an exception
    // if it's already been initialized.
    _theStaticGuid = guid;
}
```

Then, within your library, when you need that `Guid`, call a method that returns the `Guid` if it's been initialized and throws an exception if it isn't.

Something like this

```
internal Guid GetTheGuidINeed()
{
    if(_theStaticGuid == Guid.Empty) // or use nullable
        // Don't make them guess.
        throw new Exception("Really clear, helpful exception.");
    return _theStaticGuid;
}
```

This is only *if* you're tied to the static implementation. If there are lots of these values then you could use an immutable settings class. Require the consumer to initialize with an instance of the class, and validate the values in the class's constructor.

---

Another approach which eliminates the static property altogether is if you can write a class to configure your library for a DI container which is used by the consumer. Here's an example using Windsor:

```
public interface IMyLibrarySettings
{
    Guid TheGuidINeed { get; }
}

public class MyLibrarySettings : IMyLibrarySettings
{
    public MyLibrarySettings(Guid theGuidINeed)
    {
        TheGuidINeed = theGuidINeed;
    }

    public Guid TheGuidINeed { get; }
}

public class MyLibraryWindsorFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    private readonly IMyLibrarySettings _settings;

    public MyLibraryWindsorFacility(IMyLibrarySettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    protected override void Init()
    {
        // validate the settings, make sure they didn't leave stuff out
        // throw awesome clear exception messages.
        Kernel.Register(Component.For<IMyLibrarySettings>().Instance(_settings));
        // register the other dependencies in your library.
    }
}
```

Now the consumer would call

```
var settings = new MyLibrarySettings(guidThatTheySupply);
var facility = new MyLibraryWindsorFacility(settings);
container.AddFacility(facility);
```

You can do the same thing with Unity, Autofac, etc.

Now you're killing lots of birds with one stone. Your library configures its dependencies in the consumer's container, and in order to do so it requires the consumer to provide the needed settings values. When individual classes need those settings, just inject that interface into their constructors, which you can do because that type is registered with the container to return the instance that the consumer provided.

I prefer this over requiring the consumer to pass that value into the constructor unless it's a class that the consumer explicitly creates. I don't want the consumer to know what all of the various classes depend on.

Comment: Secound approach. Can you show me the example how to inject that interface into sub classes constructor? It is posible get those setting from sub class level when setting was only passed on main class init?

Comment: It's a little bit more involved. The question there is really "how do I use a dependency injection container."  Once configured, the container creates objects for you. So an interface would get injected into the class just by the class requiring it in its constructor. I know how strange that sounds. In order to point you to some good information, what is the type of the application that requires this class library - like ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core, WCF, Windows Forms, etc.?

Comment: To go a little further - it would change the way you write classes some. Each interface would be injected into the class that needs it. One class wouldn't usually have to pass it to another class. That's part of what makes it great, because it means that each class just depends on other interfaces, but it doesn't know what the implementations of those interfaces are or what they depend on. The hard part is the chicken-and-egg problem. It's hard to understand why it's so useful until you use it, but hard to start using it when it's not immediately clear what it's for.

Comment: I am creating DLL for win forms.

Comment: So can you please edit your example to include subclass?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *force* somebody to do this.

You can *document* that it needs to be done, but we all know how well that works.

You can throw an exception if it isn't done, preferably with a descriptive error message and a description how to solve this.

Even better would be to actually *pass* this Token to all methods that need it. That way it's really obvious they *need* to pass it. In addition, it's even threadsafe and they can pass multiple tokens at different times to different methods.

Comment: Guys in comments already sugested exception and passing parameter in constructor. Ill use exeption for now. Threadsafe is not the problem in my case.

Comment: @Dominik I think what nvoigt is suggesting is to get rid of the static property on the whole and instead pass that value to any function / method that actually needs it.

Comment: @Fildor I understand. Right now i am using "passing parameter in constructor" and this is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to just add a constructor that accepts this guid as a parameter. That way, the user is required to set it through the constructor, and the class cannot be instantiated without a valid guid:

```
 public class YourClass
 {
      public YourClass(Guid token)
      {
           // Validate token and throw exception if not valid
           Token = token;
      }

      public static Guid Token { get; set; }
 }
```

With this approach, the dependencies become clear as well. Additionally, you can put a check in the set as well to make sure it cannot be set to Guid.Empty.

Comment: Not in my case with a lot of classes. Using constructor force me to pass parameter when using sub classes. The point is to set static property *once* and use it internaly in each classes.

Comment: Well then, just create this class as I described, create one instance of it, and inject that instance into your other classes.

Comment: I have seen a pattern in C-Libs: They tend to have a dedicated "Initiate" Function that needs to be called first before using any other functions ... not a perfect solution, but maybe an idea.

Comment: But then you rely on the consumer to actually call it. They can choose not to call it, and then it fails. Better to enforce it, by making sure you cannot initiate any class if the guid is not set.

Comment: @L-Four absolutely agreed. That's why I would prefer nvoigt's proposition to just pass the value to any function that actually needs it and drop having it as a static property altogether.

Comment: Right now all my classes and sub-classes are init by passing parameter in constructor. I am trying to avoid that, because it scale bad. That's why i am asking for another solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but passing dependencies in constructor is considered best practice :) and I have no idea why you say it 'scales bad'? Anyway, I hope you find a solution that works for you :)